# How to make Ubuntu ask for TTLS credentials on every login

Tags: network-manager, internet

We 're thinking of switching our computer labs with Windows to Ubuntu. The only problem we faced during testing is that there is no equivalent of SecureW2 on Ubuntu. I know that we can use NetworkManager to establish the connection. The problem is, Ubuntu shouldn't save the credentials, so that every student who wants to use that PC must enter their user ID (e.g. studentname@universitydomain.edu) and the password. Is it possible? And I would love to hear any recommendations to use as login screen (like the one of SecureW2). Thanks in advance.

PS. We use ethernet connection, not the wifi.